# Rails 3 Sending errors to email

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling

How do I hijack Rails (3) error handling to email errors with full trace to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your considered [HopToad](http://hoptoadapp.com/pages/home)?

**UPDATE:** HopToad is now known as [Airbrake](http://airbrake.io/pages/home)

Comment: Airbrake is now $80/mo. for the cheapest plan.

Answer (score 6):

Exception Notifier Plugin for Rails
https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification

Answer (score 1):

Haven't done it myself yet, but you should be able to use the [log4r](http://log4r.rubyforge.org/index.html) gem and substitute that for the stock rails logger. This can be done in `environment.rb`, see for example [this blog post](http://blog.martyandrews.net/2007/09/logging-in-ruby-on-rails.html).

Then you would instruct `log4r` to send emails on errors, see [documentation](http://log4r.rubyforge.org/rdoc/Log4r/EmailOutputter.html)

Answer (score 1):

- Hoptoad:  http://hoptoadapp.com/pages/home
- ErrorApp: http://errorapp.com/
- ExceptionNotifier:   https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification