# Capturing an Exception before default error pages are rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails 3 Sending errors to email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441018/rails-3-sending-errors-to-email)

I want to add custom code that sends the Admin an email each time there is a system failure and the default error files 404 and 500  are rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [exception_notifier](http://rubygems.org/gems/exception_notifier) gem – it is capable of sending emails with exception details to the address you configure.

As for 404 errors – it might a bit tricky to catch, you have to setup a wildcard route for that. In addition to that, sending emails on every 404 might be a bad option (these happen quite a few times for live sites).

Comment: Thanks. Where can i add the code that uses this gem?

Comment: Just follow the instructions at http://rubydoc.info/gems/exception_notifier/1.0.0/frames, you just need to set it up and enable for you app – the rest is handled by the gem.